# Fragment overflowing tab host

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement a tab host that controls a fragment. Depending on the tab that is selected, the fragment will fetch different data from an api call.

The problem is that the fragment is occupying the space where the tab selector should be. I see the tab text but my fragment is behind it.

I want the fragment to start right below the tab selector.

Here's a picture of the UI:

http://postimg.org/image/sxj58t0qx/

This is the activity's xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.example.madelenko.movierating.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tabhost">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <TabWidget
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/tabs"
                            android:orientation="vertical"/>

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/fake_frame">

                            <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                android:id="@+id/gridview"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:numColumns="@integer/column_count"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/grid_vert_spacing"
                                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>
                        </FrameLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>


        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And this is the fragment itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/grid_element_parent">

    <!-- View to be populated with a movie poster-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <!--View to be populated with the movie's title and rating-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/text_overlay_height"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:textColor="#00000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/overlay_text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally this is my oncreate method from the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.fake_frame);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(POPULAR).setIndicator(POPULAR),
            MovieListFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(HIGHEST_RATED).setIndicator(HIGHEST_RATED),
            MovieListFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(FAVOURITE).setIndicator(FAVOURITE),
            MovieListFragment.class, null);


    //We check if the layout selected has two fragments
    if (findViewById(R.id.movie_detail_container) != null) {
        //If it has two, we update our member variable
        mTwoPane = true;
        /*If the activity has been recently created, we replace the placeholder
        frameview with the actual detail fragment
         */
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(
                            R.id.movie_detail_container,
                            new DetailActivityFragment(),
                            DETAIL_TAG
                    ).commit();
        }
    } else {
        mTwoPane = false;
    }
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}
```

How can I position them correctly?

Comment: Please show the code which creates the TabHost and loads the fragment.

Comment: I think you should use ViewPager instead of TabHost. I'm not very experienced with either of these, so I'm not entirely sure about the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TabHost` is deprecated. You should use `TabLayout` instead.